# Is there a purpose to hitting the spikes in Wings of Vi?

Tags: wings-of-vi

I'm watching someone play [Wings of Vi](http://www.grynsoft.com/wov). He noticed that the static floor spikes can take damage. Most of the hits are 0 damage, but occasionally you see a 1. Is there a purpose to this? Can I kill them?

Comment: I doubt it. in most games like this while they might allow some entities to take damage, they either have no "health bar", meaning there is no health to deplete, or the health bar is so massively huge, it'd be pointless anyway, especially if you're only *occasionally* dealing 1 damage.

Comment: Some games like to hide things like easter eggs behind silly tedious task, such as hitting an object over and over again. Similarly, this game also has small dark clouds that the damage counts up as you hit them more. The fellow I was watching got up to about 150 before giving up on those.